How to leverage pyannote / speaker-diarization-3.0 with Transformers.js?
pyannote/segmentation-3.0 suggests to use pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.0 since it has better embedding model for diarization. I am trying to use this in client-side JS. It seems like I am supposed to use Transformers.js. Here is how I can use it client side for pyannote/segmentation-3.0. However, I am not sure how to use Transformers.js for pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.0. I am new to this. Can someone please help me? Thank you!
